# Not receiving emails in Yahoo account using mailgun in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mailgun, yahoo, email

I'm receiving mail in another accounts such as gmail, hotmail, etc...
**but not getting on yahoo, Below error log from mailgun account.**

> Server response: 554 Message not allowed - [PH01] Email not accepted for policy reasons. Please visit https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN5067.html [120]

Comment: As I understand this, your spam is being blocked and you would like someone to write a workaround for you?

Comment: This means you need to work on your email being too spammy. There are many things that determine why Yahoo is seeing your email as spam. For instance, if you're not using SMTP you should be. Try sending some mail over to mailtrap for analysis.

Comment: Yes, I am sending mail via  SMTP